# reading only few fields from a text file with multiple delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file with multiple delimiters separating the value. from that I just want to read the pipe separated values

data is like this for example:
'
10|10|10|10|10|10|10|10|10;10:10:10,10,10,10 ... etc
'

I want to read only upto the 8 pipe separated values as a dataframe and ignore the values with ";,:". How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a two step process. First read csv with `|` as delimiter

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"10|10|10|10|10|10|10|10|10;10:10:10,10,10,10"
), delimiter='|', header=None)

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10;10:10:10,10,10,10
```

Then update the last column by removing the string coming after `[;,:]`

```
df.iloc[:, -1] = df.iloc[:, -1].str.replace(r'[;,:].*', '', regex=True)
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
```

If you know the exact character after which you have to ignore, you can use `comment` attribute as follows. Everything after that 1 char string would be ignored.

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"10|10|10|10|10|10|10|10|10;10:10:10,10,10,10"
), delimiter='|', header=None, comment=';')
df
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
```

Comment: I agree about the 2 step process , but the main reason I want to do this is to decrease the read time. Can this be done at once? Because i assume just reading upto '|' delimiter will take lesser time than reading the whole row

Comment: Thanks for raising this. It is possible but only if you know the exact character after which you have to ignore. For the current example, it is possible. I have updated the answer

Comment: You can `usecols` if you know the exact column nos to be read, like `usecols=[3,4,5]`

Answer (score 0):

This is longer than other proposed solutions, but also possibly faster because it only reads what's needed. It collects the result as a list but it could be another container type :

```
df      =  "10,10,10,10|10|10|10|10|10|10|10|10;10:10:10,10,10,10"
coll    = []
start   = 0
prevIdx = -1
while True:
    try:
        idx = df.index("|", start)
        if prevIdx >= 0: 
            n = int(df[prevIdx+1:idx])
            if isinstance(n, int): coll.append(n)
        start   = idx+1
        prevIdx = idx
    except:
        break;
print(coll) # ==> [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```